# How get get previous node value in mustache

Tags: templates, mustache

I have a object, which has multiple objects

```
fields:[
  {
     safeName: 'status',
     accessorName: 'Status',
     type: {name: 'String', doc: 'String', code: '\'String\''},
     field: {type: 'string', description: 'pet status in the store', enum: ['available', 'pending', 'sold']}
  },
  {

     safeName: 'code',
     accessorName: 'Code',
     type: {name: 'NSInteger', doc: 'NSInteger', code: '\'NSInteger\'' },
     field: {type: 'integer', format: 'int32'}
  },
  ... 
]
```

I need to check with enum value

Output should be

When `enum` is present in field

`instance.status = Order.Status(rawValue: (sourceDictionary["status"] as? String) ?? "")`

And when `enum is not present` in `field` object

`instance.code = Decoders.decodeOptional(clazz: NSInteger.self, source: sourceDictionary["code"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did like this

```
{{#fields}}{{#field}}
  {{#description}}
    instance.{{safeName}} = Order.Status(rawValue: (sourceDictionary["{{safeName}}"] as? String) ?? "")
  {{/description}} 
  {{^description}}
    instance.{{safeName}} = Decoders.decodeOptional(clazz: {{#type}}{{type.name}}{{/type}}.self, source: sourceDictionary["code"])
  {{/description}
{{/field}}{{/fields}}
```